# Spring boot security passes bad credentials

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I created a very simple http basic security for a Springboot app, the app deploys and I put the user and password. The problem is that if I call again with a different password, the request still counts as correct, instead of rejecting it.But if I change the user, then the application rejects my request and waits for the correct username and password.

my code:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The result with good credentials: [The json output is as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa3fE.png)

The result with bad credentials: [The json output is still as if it was succesfull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZtIf.png)

The result with different user: [The app behaves like expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM7yR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected for `httpBasic()`, [see the `BasicAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/c7912c551b94a5f617cfa6b4d821926d28dc12ce/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java#L201-L223).

After the first request, you should have a `JSESSIONID` cookie, which will be used to authenticate further requests. This behavior avoids doing the basic authentication flow every time a request comes in. The only reason to reauthenticate is if the HTTP Basic `username` is different from the authenticated user's username.